# Python Any checa demais elementos mesmo retornando uma opção True com o primeiro

Tags: python

Estou com uma dúvida com relação ao funcionamento do *built-in* `any` do Python:

```py
variavel = None

any([not variavel, variavel.get("chave1"), variavel.get("chave2")])
```

Ao meu ver, se o primeiro item do a lista fosse `True`, o `any` já retornaria `True` e vida que segue.

[Na própria documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#any), mostra um exemplo equivalente ao que eu acreditava que seria o comportamento correto.

Porém, fui testar no terminal dentro do Pycharm:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E aparentemente, mesmo a primeira condição retornando `True`, ele continua checando os demais itens. Eu acredito que estou fazendo alguma caquinha, mas já testei em outros ambientes e o resultado que encontro é o mesmo. Todos os ambientes estão utilizando Python 3.8.3.

Comment: o problema não está no teste lógico. `None` não tem nenhum método chamado `get`

Comment: sim, mas a dúvida surgiu pq essa validação rola dentro de um contexto que espera um dict. No teste, fiz uma requisição passando None e não {}, esperando que fosse exatamente o mesmo comportamento, afinal, como está dentro de um any, a primeira checagem já retornaria True, então tanto faz se eu uso um meodo do dict ou de outro tipo qualquer, pq em teroria, nem chegaria a abter no próximo elemento

Comment: Não entendi o porquê dos negativos, é uma dúvida pertinente. O único problema da pergunta é print de erro ao invés de colocar como texto.

Comment: sim.. nao entendi os negativos tbm, mas ta de boa. o print foi vacilo, devia ter copiado e colado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quando você faz:

```py
variavel = None

any([not variavel, variavel.get("chave1"), variavel.get("chave2")])
```

É "o mesmo" que você tivesse feito:

```py
variavel = None
lista = [not variavel, variavel.get("chave1"), variavel.get("chave2")]
any(lista)
```

O interpretador precisa ler, executar e criar sua lista antes de passar para a função `any`.

Se você espera se aproveitar do comportamento "short-circuit" da linguagem você tem duas opções:

1. Usando IF, assim o interpretador não executa nada depois de saber que o resultado é verdadeiro. Exemplo:

   ```py
   variavel = None
   if (
       not variavel
       or variavel.get("chave1")
       or variavel.get("chave2")
   ):
       print(f"Usando IF: True")
   else:
       print(f"Usando IF: False")
   ```
2. Usando um gerador de valores juntamente com o `any`, assim o `any` só lê o primeiro valor e já retorna o resultado, nunca executando o código que gera o erro. Exemplo:

   ```py
   def gera_valores():
       variavel = None
       yield not variavel
       yield variavel.get("chave1")
       yield variavel.get("chave2")

   resultado = any(gera_valores())
   print(f"Usando ANY: {resultado!r}")  # True
   ```

<sup>Códigos rodando no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@fernandosavio/SOPt-516274-6333)</sup>

Comment: boa. vlw Fernando

Comment: @MauroMartinsJúnior se você acha que essa é uma boa resposta pode marcar como aceita para os visitantes do futuro saberem que resolve o seu problema ou explica sua dúvida. Qualquer dúvida a central de ajudas tem a página ["O que eu devo fazer se alguém responder minha pergunta?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). ;)

Comment: Feito. Obrigado mais uma vez